# HTML tel: link to emergency number

Tags: html, rfc, tel

How do I create a HTML `<a href="tel:"></a>` link to an emergency number like `911` or `112`?

The [RFC says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-5.1)

> The
> phone number can be represented in either global or local
> notation.  All phone numbers MUST use the global form unless they
> cannot be represented as such.
> [Emergency numbers ("911", "112")] cannot be represented in global form and
> need to be represented as a local number with a context.

From the [local-context section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-5.1.5) I don't find it easy to understand what a "local-context" is, let alone what the correct one for this case is. It lists domain prefixes like `houston.example.com` or a numeric prefix like `+1`, and in one paragraph it says

> A context consisting of the initial digits of a global number does
> not imply that adding these to the local number will generate a valid
> E.164 number.  It might do so by coincidence, but this cannot be
> relied upon.  (For example, "911" should be labeled with the context
> "+1", but "+1-911" is not a valid E.164 number.)

But the phrasing of this paragraph is again very confusing.

Is

```
<a href="tel:+49-112">112</a>
```

now the correct way of doing it, and the fact that it is not a valid E.164 number is irrelevant?

Or is the fact that it is not a valid E.164 number a problem?

[In some other places](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/changeset/82/pjproject/trunk/pjsip/src/test-pjsip/uri.c) I see people using

```
<a href="tel:112;phone-context=emergency.example.com">112</a>
```

And again [other people recommend](https://books.google.de/books?id=dEpz2sq82Y4C&pg=PT266&lpg=PT266&dq=tel+phone-context+112&source=bl&ots=xYOpMKyoq2&sig=xZlnTo0J2o-xrXBx8lSHftB-m98&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK89al3NLZAhXO_aQKHc-GA40Q6AEIVzAE#v=onepage&q=tel%20phone-context%20112&f=false)

```
<a href="tel:112;phone-context=+49">112</a>
```

But when I tap that link on Android, the dialer opens with the number

```
112;746632668398+49
```

Comment: That local-context section also says "The parameter value is defined by the assignee of the local number." So, I'm not sure there's a way for the general public (e.g., SO members) to answer that question globally...

Comment: Hi @Nils, have you found a way to make it? I have similar issues and I need a link to 911.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited [Section 5.1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-5.1.5) the RFC states

> A context consisting of the initial digits of a global number does
> not imply that adding these to the local number will generate a valid
> E.164 number.  It might do so by coincidence, but this cannot be
> relied upon.  (For example, "911" should be labeled with the context
> "+1", but "+1-911" is not a valid E.164 number.)

I interpret this that emergency numbers should be prefixed by their country-secific prefixes, i.e.

- in the US, `911` should be used as `<a href="tel:+1-911">911</a>`
- in Germany `112` should be used as `<a href="tel:+49-112">112</a>`

The rest of the paragraph is about this syntax not being compliant to the E.164 recommendation. As far as I understand, E.164 is irrelevant in this context though.